# How to filter lines with the same date in different formats

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, date

I have a txt file like this:

```
./201709.15.txt:88:word word TAG201709152000 word word
./201709.19.txt:3:word TAG201709152000 word word
./201710.10.txt:5:word word TAG201709152000 word word word
```

and I need to filter only the lines as:

```
./201709.15.txt:88:word word TAG201709152000 word word
```

(i.e. with the same date at the beginning: `./YYYMM.dd.txt` and after TAG: `TAGYYYYMMddhhmm`)

Is it possible with shell script?

Comment: the 3rd item `2017010` does not correspond `YYYMM`. typo?

Comment: Even if the last line in your example `./2017010.10` would be correct, it'd be a different date. What part do you want to be matched?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I corrected the typo (it was 201710)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
grep -E '/([0-9]{6})\.([0-9]{2}).* TAG\1\2' file
```

Comment: Good solution. Two remarks: 1) Backreferences are not required by the extended regular expressions standard , so this may not work with all versions of `grep`. Use `grep '/\([0-9]\{6\}\)\.\([0-9]\{2\}\).* TAG\1\2' file` instead (although it's less readable). 2) Are you sure that @Arianna will understand this without an explanation?

Answer (score 2):

**Awk** solution:

```
awk -F'.' 'match($4,/TAG[0-9]{8}/) && substr($4,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3) == substr($2$3,2)' file
```

The output:

```
./201709.15.txt:88:word word TAG201709152000 word word
```

Comment: `++` Nice `Awk` usage, but am curious to know if the OP needs to change the way the o/p is pushed (or) this much complex processing is needed

Comment: @Inian, you know how it goes: If we don't have enough details - we rely on the current input and the current expected result